# Select menu displaying multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a select HTML control like the following:

```
 <select name="width-dimension-inches" id="width-dimension-inches"  data-bind="value: widthWhole,jqmSelectMenuRefresh :true, options: widthDimension.dimension.getDimensionsWhole()">

</select>
```

I created a custom knockout binding called jqmSelectMenuRefresh because whenever I selected an option from the select list I was not able to see it in the select list. The implementation for jqmSelectMenuRefresh is shown below:

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "jqueryMobile"], function ($, ko) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.jqmSelectMenuRefresh = {

        init: function(element) {

            $(element).selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);

        },
```

When I run the above code I end up with two selectmenus as shown below:

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?

**UPDATE 1:**

If I update the code to the following:

```
  init: function(element) {

            $(element).selectmenu('refresh',true);
```

then I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you invoke `selectmenu()` function the new instance is created.

```
$(element).selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

The above line of code will create two instances which ends up with two visible elements.

My suggestion is to initialize plugin, store the instance in variable and then invoke function on this object:

```
var $instance = $(element).selectmenu();
$instance.selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: I tried your code and it still creates two select lists since you are also calling it twice.